# TS2307: Cannot find module 'ionic/ionic'

Tags: typescript, angular, tsc, tsconfig, ionic2

When trying to use `tsc` with my ionic2 project, i am getting the following error on a typescript file.

The Error:
`TS2307: Cannot find module 'ionic/ionic'`

---

The Code:

```
import {Page} from "ionic/ionic" //error happens on this line

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'app/list/list.html',
})
export class ListPage {
  constructor() {}
}
```

---

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

---

My npm -g list:

```
cordova@5.4.0
ionic@2.0.0-alpha.23
npm@3.4.1
typescript@1.6.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [issue 84](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2/issues/84)

We still need to create a definition file for ionic 2. So until then, the typescript compiler will yell a lot, but it will still compile the code correctly.

Comment: Thanks again! Tracking the issue.

Comment: Link is dead :(

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been resolved in `"ionic-framework": "2.0.0-alpha.38"`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on *ionic2.0.0-beta.17*

For typescript need to **change import path for all core components**.

In your case from

**import {Page} from "ionic/ionic"**

to

**import {Page} from 'ionic-framework/ionic'**

P.s: this is just for typescript. For native JS ionic2 app path remains the same (ionic/ionic).

Answer (score -1):

Yo need to include the ionic typescript definition file.
You can download it from here
https://www.nuget.org/packages/cordova-ionic.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/

Comment: I used `tsd` to install `cordova-ionic` and it did not fix the issue.